# Gas mixture flow rate equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

2 gas flows connect and mix in a pipe.
The following is known:

$\dot{m_1}$; $\dot{m_2}$ - mass flow rate of the inlet gases $(\frac{kg}{s})$

$A_1$; $A_2$; $A_{mix}$ - the cross section of the pipes $(m^2)$

$\rho_1$; $\rho_2$ - the densities of the 2 gases

$T_1 = T_2 = T_{mix} $

**We are looking for the following:**

$Q_{mix}$ - flow rate of the mixture $(\frac{m^3}{s})$

So far I have been able to get only this:

> $\dot{m_1} + \dot{m_2} = \dot{m}_{mix}$ (1)
>
> $\dot{m}=\rho*A*V$    (2)
>
> $\dot{m} = \rho*Q $   (3)
>
> $\dot{m_1} + \dot{m_2} = \rho_{mix}*Q_{mix}$ (4)
>
> $Q_{mix} = \frac{\dot{m_1} + \dot{m_2}}{\rho_{mix}} $ (5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

> $$\rho_{mix}= \frac{\dot m_1 + \dot m_2}{\dot Q_1 + \dot Q_2}$$

and not 
$$\rho_{mix}= \frac{\dot Q_1 + \dot Q_2}{\dot m_1 + \dot m_2}$$

You can easily verify this by considering $\dot m $ and $\dot Q$ as $\frac{dm}{dt}$ and $\frac{dV}{dt}$ respectively, where $V$ is the volume. So the equation becomes 
$$\rho_{mix}= \frac{\frac{dm_1}{dt} + \frac{dm_2}{dt}}{\frac{dV_1}{dt} + \frac{dV_2}{dt}}$$
$$\rho_{mix}= \frac{dm_1 + dm_2}{dV_1 + dV_2}$$
$$\therefore \rho_{mix}= \frac{dm_{total}}{dV_{total}}$$

and that is the standard definition of density($\frac mV$).

P.S. you should use $v$ instead of $V$ in equation (2). I was confusing it with volume instead of velocity till now!